# Sequelize Where Not Exist Query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I just moved from laravel to nodejs and i am using sequelize to map to my mysql database, i have been trying to convert an sql query into sequelize

```
select * from `messages` where ((`to` = ? and `from` = ? and `recipient_type` = ? and `timer` is null)) or ((`to` = ? and `from` = ? and `recipient_type` = ? and `timer` is null)) and not exists (select * from `message_deletes` where `messages`.`mid` = `message_deletes`.`message_id` and `user_id` = ?) order by `id` desc limit 100
```

Can Someone please help out. Thank YOu

Comment: Check the docs for raw queries : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html

Comment: Thank You for your response, so there is no way to use the orm to generate the query?

Comment: This is a parameterized Query, so I tried to search for such kind.